# SQLite in android, how to iterate through entire database column and apply its values to recycler view

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-recyclerview

I have a big SQLite database (7000+ items) with 16 columns per row. I would like to populate my custom recycler view, that I already made, with items from the database to make a huge recycler view list. 
My question is this: How would you go about iterating through 2 entire columns of all of the rows. I need to fetch a `name` and an `ID` of each and every single item in the database and assign those values to 2 text views, that I created through a custom recycler view adapter. I already have a method in the database that returns a number of total rows (aka items) in a database. I would like to make a loop with `i < getDbSize();` but I don't have a clear idea on how I would go about on incrementing through 2 particular columns of all rows and then applying that information onto a card in the recycler view.
Here is the xml code where recycler view sits:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".CollegeFragment"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="College Search Tool"
            android:textSize="28sp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/grad_bg"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="ipeds id:"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"/>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_ipeds"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                    android:paddingRight="15dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/et_alt1_bg"/>


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="name:    "
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"/>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                    android:paddingRight="15dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/et_alt1_bg"/>

            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="RESULT"
            android:textSize="28sp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"/>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

and Java:

```
public class CollegeFragment extends Fragment implements ItemClickListener{

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private CustomRecyclerAdapter customRecyclerAdapter;
    private List<CollegeItem> collegeItemList = new ArrayList<>();
    private DatabaseCollege dbCollege;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_college, container, false);

        dbCollege = new DatabaseCollege(getActivity());

        recyclerView = myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.recycler);
        customRecyclerAdapter = new CustomRecyclerAdapter(collegeItemList, getActivity());

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(customRecyclerAdapter);
        customRecyclerAdapter.setItemClickListener(this);

        //populate collegeItemList with dummy values for testing
        String name = "College 1";
        String id = "12345647653";
        String name2 = "College 2";
        String id2 = "12345";
        CollegeItem college = new CollegeItem(name, id);
        CollegeItem college2 = new CollegeItem(name2, id2);


        collegeItemList.add(college);
        collegeItemList.add(college2);
        return myFragmentView;

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v, int position) {
        String name = collegeItemList.get(position).getName();
        String id = collegeItemList.get(position).getId();
    }

    public void populateList() {
        int numOfColleges = dbCollege.getNumOfColleges();
        for(int i = 0; i < numOfColleges; i++) {
        //read in data from database into collegeItemList recyclerView here 
        }
    }
}
```

I also included a picture with what I am trying to achieve that contains manually inserted variables. I basically want to populate that list with cards that each contain info(ID and name) about each and every item from database.[image: sample of recyclerView]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to query the database first to get those two fields like below:

```
    ArrayList<CollegeItem> arr = new ArrayList<>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    // Move to first row
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false)
    {
        arr.add(new CollegeItem(cursor.getString(1), 
        cursor.getString(2)); 
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return arr;
```

Then pass this ArrayList(arr) to the list view using Adaptor and map the values of Pair class to the XML components.